# Interpretation of a sum involving expected value and raw moments

Tags: probability, expectation

Given
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}[X^n]-\mathbb{E}[X]^n}{n!}
$$
where $X$ stands as a random variable whose expected value exists.

How can I interpret the difference among the *n-th* raw moment of $X$ and the expected value raised to the *n-th* power?

Comment: Looks like $E(e^X)-e^{E(X)}$.

Comment: You are right, this is where I come from actually. I'm trying to address the Jensen's gap for the exponential function.